# Android Dimens Value calculation for different values folders

Tags: android, android-layout

I am giving size in dimen value for some UI components.My UI need to be supported by all devices in portrait mode so I put my dimen files into 16 folders

[image]

At first I inserted values in **values-normal-xhdpi** (as I have the device to test) .So now I have built my dimen file for values-normal-xhdpi folder.Now I am doing entries in **values-normal-hdpi** by again checking visual effect for normal-hdpi screen.This is really a hectic task **I need some formula so that I can evaluate the value of dimens for remaining of folders.**

Some of android standards says that **drawable image** should be in  these ratio:

**ldpi =0.75**

**mdpi =1.0**

**hdpi =1.5**

**xhdpi =2**

**but this is not working here as dimen value 100 dp for values-normal-mdpi is not give same effect as value 150 dp gives in values-normal-hdpi**

My dimens.xml for values-normal-xhdpi

```
<resources>
    <!-- this is used in note -->
    <dimen name="text_size_h1">60sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size_h2">50sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size_h3">40sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size_h4">30sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size_h5">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size_h6">20sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="text_size_h8">11sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size_h10">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size_h12">8sp</dimen>


    <dimen name="extra_mini">2dp</dimen>


    <dimen name="mini">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="x_mini">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xx_mini">14dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xxx_mini">20dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="mid">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="x_mid">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xx_mid">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xxx_mid">60dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="max">70dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="x_max">62dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xx_max">90dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xxx_max">100dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="supper">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="x_supper">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xx_supper">130dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="xxx_supper">140dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="xxxxxx_supper">180dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="image_width">628dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_height">270dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Comment: All you need is `values` (which is `values-normal`), `values-large`, and possibly `values-xlarge` and `values-small`. Dimensions in `dp` are automatically converted based on the pixel density of the device, so all you need to do is provide different dimensions to scale UI elements based on screen size (i.e. larger margins for larger screens).

Answer (score 3):

"dp" are **Density Independent Pixels**. 100dp means 100px in mdpi, 150px in hdpi, 200px in xhdpi, &c.

This means that you do not need to specify values for each density variant if you always use dp (which is a good idea), they are converted automatically to pixels values for each one.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms

> Density-independent pixel (dp)
>
> A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to
>   express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
>   The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a
>   160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system
>   for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently
>   handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual
>   density of the screen in use.

Comment: When I give width of a button 100dp then It will not give same effect on all devices . We have to give dimen values in different values folder.

Comment: Some device are 240dp so dp gives different effect on 160dp and 240dp devices.

Comment: Be careful, it looks like you're confusing dpi (i.e. hdpi screens are 240dpi) with dp? A button with a size specified as 100dp should look "approximately the same size" in every device, irrespective of its display density.

Comment: Wait so this means if I use dp for specifying all the values then I don't need to adjust for different devices. If I write something as 100dp then it will automatically work for all devices, irrespective of hdpi/xhdpi/mdpi, etc.

Why would I then have different values folders like values-sw800dp, values-sw800dp-xhpdi, and so on? Wouldn't it just be sufficient to have one values folder with one dp dimen that works for all?

Comment: @user2759617 The -swXXXdp are for using different resources for screens of different logical size (think phones or tablets). Also, while dp are fine for view sizes, bitmaps and other resources should have variants for different densities.